# how to format date received from database and use it in jquery function

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I have a column in table in mm-dd-yyyy format. and i have the following script to disable some dates in the date picker.

```
 <script>
 jQuery(function($){
//var disabledDays = <?php echo json_encode($dates); ?>;
 var disabledDays = [
 "27-4-2016", "25-12-2017", "26-12-2017",
 "4-3-2017", "5-4-2017", "6-4-2017", "6-4-2016", "7-4-2017", "8-4-2017", "9-4-2017"
];
//replace these with the id's of your datepickers
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
    var day = date.getDay();
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('d-m-yy', date);
    var isDisabled = ($.inArray(string, disabledDays) != -1);
//day != 0 disables all Sundays
//return [day != 0 && !isDisabled];
return [!isDisabled];

}});
$("#datepicker").on("change",function(){
            var selected = $(this).val();
             $("#date").text(selected);
              $('input[name="date"]').attr('value', selected);
        });
}); 
  </script>
```

I am using this to pick the dates from mysql database.

```
$sql="select display_date from login_ads where display_type='static'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($static_purchased_dates = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $dates[] =  $static_purchased_dates['display_date'];
}
echo json_encode($dates);
```

which returns dates in this format:

```
["03\/04\/2017","03\/04\/2017"]
```

My question is how to retrieve date from mysql like the format used in the script to disable dates.

I am very new to PHP and thanks advance for helping.

Thanks

Comment: This is a varchar data type of column?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The dates in `disabledDates` are not in` mm-dd-yyyy` format as you say they are in `m-d-yyyy` format (note the missing preceiding zeros required for `mm` or `dd`. Also, what have you tried? A Google search for "php date format" or "mysql date format" will give you lots of good starting places.

Answer (score 0):

you can use some PHP to solve your problem.
You can do like this :

```
$sql="select display_date from login_ads where display_type='static'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($static_purchased_dates = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $static_purchased_dates['display_date']);
    $dates[] =  $date->format('Y-n-d');
}
echo json_encode($dates);
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. the above code showing the date as per the jqery function but that was not working in the function.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your table column display_date is probably in format "mm/dd/yyyy" (not "mm-dd-yyyy") so json_encode convert it to "mm\/dd\/yyyy".

According to line:

```
var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('d-m-yy', date);
```

you need "mm/dd/yyyy" convert to "d-m-yyyy" (without leading zeros for days and months).

First option (w/o DateTime):

```
$sql="select display_date from login_ads where display_type='static'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($static_purchased_dates = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $tempD = $static_purchased_dates['display_date'];

    $tempD = substr($tempD,3,2).'-'.substr($tempD,0,2).'-'.substr($tempD,6,6);
    $tempD = str_replace('-0', '-', $tempD);
    if( substr($tempD,0,1) == '0' )
      $tempD = substr($tempD,1);

    $dates[] = $tempD;
}
echo json_encode($dates);
```

Second option (w/ DateTime):

```
$sql="select display_date from login_ads where display_type='static'";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
while ($static_purchased_dates = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
    $tempD = $static_purchased_dates['display_date'];

    $tempDT = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $tempD);
    $dates[] =  $tempDT->format('j-n-Y');
}
echo json_encode($dates);
```

PHP DateTime formats: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: 2nd options works for me. grateful to you; you've saved a lot of my time. thanks

Comment: Hi @BanglaTiger if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.